# node.js controlling relative filepaths in different environments - pm2 vs vanilla node for example

Tags: node.js

I have a line of code:

```
var currentDir = './src/config';
fs.readdirSync(currentDir).forEach(function(dir) {...
```

This works fine on Mac, but on Ubuntu I'm getting an error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './src/config'
```

On mac I'm using node v5.5.0

on Ubuntu I'm using node v0.10.25, and using pm2.

======= Edit

See below for comments on the solution

Comment: Have you tried on the same node version on both OS X and Ubuntu? Also, does that directory exist? Have you tried using an absolute path?

Comment: I am using pm2, which was doing 'funny stuff' - what that stuff is i have no idea. As a workaround I created a path.js file in the root which had the line exports.rootDir = __dirname;. Then I just load that file whenever I need it

Comment: It seems that whenever i used './path', the path was relative to where the function was being called, as opposed to the file. Do you know why pm2 changes this?

Comment: When using a relative path, it will be relative to the cwd of the process. I would probably go for using an absolute path by resolving the relative file path to wherever you need it to be to be on the safe side. If it is relative to the file, you can use `path.join(__dirname, './src/config')`

Comment: Thanks. that is a better solution. so cwd stands for 'current working directory'? how is that defined by the pm2 process?

Comment: The question makes no sense now that I have figured out the problem

Comment: @ZachSmith If you use json file to declare your app you can set cwd to be used by pm2. See this http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question was the comment by Evan Lucas:

> *When using a relative path, it will be relative to the `cwd` of the process. I would probably go for using an absolute path by resolving the relative file path to wherever you need it to be to be on the safe side. If it is relative to the file, you can use `path.join(__dirname, './src/config')`*